# Download from app store

Tags: iphone, ios

When I want to download from App Store it is asking me to switch to US store or KWT or Saudi store.how I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

You see the prompt if the App Store is set to a country which is different from your iTunes account. Your option is to either sign in (with an existing or create a new ) iTunes account belonging to that country. There is another option which is to change your current iTunes account's country to that country, but you'll LOSE any credit balance.

Comment: I once requested support for country switching thing. And there's a lot of things and details, so if you are to switch your account to another country, I recommend STRONGLY to request a support and have someone explain all the details.

Comment: Agree 100% with Shane, highly recommend you do this at an Apple Retail (not Online) Store if possible so there's an Apple Genius to help walk you through the steps.